# How to load gzipped json data from a copy

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

```
COPY tmp_data FROM 's3://mybucket/copy/batch_insert_data_1417072335118.json'  credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=YyYYYyyYYYYYyyYYYYyyYYYYY' json gzip ACCEPTINVCHARS ' ' TRUNCATECOLUMNS TRIMBLANKS;
```

Above COPY command works without gzip. But Now i want to use the gzip to speed up the process. Now im uploading a gzipped json file into S3 bucket. But the above copy command does not work? any idea how to load a gzipped json file from COPY in Redshift?

Comment: I don't think command are case sensitive but doc says GZIP.  Can you try ?http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html.  Also, can you provide details about the error message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing json_option (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html). Try setting it 'auto'. See corrected example below:

```
COPY tmp_data FROM 's3://mybucket/copy/batch_insert_data_1417072335118.json'  credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=YyYYYyyYYYYYyyYYYYyyYYYYY' json 'auto' gzip ACCEPTINVCHARS ' ' TRUNCATECOLUMNS TRIMBLANKS;
```

Comment: If you have `S3 path "AUTO" has invalid format.` while using this solution, try to use `'auto'` in lowercase instead of `'AUTO'`